# Spark 1.5.2: Worker unable to persist broadcast to disk

Tags: apache-spark

I have a long running process executing Spark jobs against a standalone Spark cluster with 2 worker nodes.  Initially, jobs complete successfully but it seems that after a day or two, some jobs will begin to fail.  All the failing jobs are a result of failures in stages running on the same worker which logs the following sequence and exception to the `stderr` log:

```
16/05/04 21:07:53 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2273) called with curMem=988397261, maxMem=1159641169
16/05/04 21:07:53 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_259_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.2 KB, free 163.3 MB)
16/05/04 21:07:53 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 259 took 9 ms
16/05/04 21:07:53 WARN MemoryStore: Failed to reserve initial memory threshold of 1024.0 KB for computing block broadcast_259 in memory.
16/05/04 21:07:53 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache broadcast_259 in memory! (computed 504.0 B so far)
16/05/04 21:07:53 INFO MemoryStore: Memory use = 942.6 MB (blocks) + 162.9 MB (scratch space shared across 0 tasks(s)) = 1105.5 MB. Storage limit = 1105.9 MB.
16/05/04 21:07:53 WARN MemoryStore: Persisting block broadcast_259 to disk instead.
16/05/04 21:07:53 WARN BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_259 failed
16/05/04 21:07:53 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 259
16/05/04 21:07:53 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 220.0 (TID 2575)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/aetmpdir/spark/tmp/spark-4de0f2b6-6d96-41f8-9d28-9e9d288f143a/executor-d2b171a9-377d-4857-9754-c41332ceda66/blockmgr-ed82e9b2-bc90-4069-bd89-ed0e7f57468c/28/broadcast_259 (A file or directory in the path name does not exist.)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:233)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.putIterator(DiskStore.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:791)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1175)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
```

Looking at the filesystem on that node, it is clear that the numbered sub-directory in the blockmgr directory (in this case`28`) does not exist which seems to be the root of the FileNotFoundException.  However, there are other directories at that same level.

For comparison, on the working node, I will see the following sequence in the log:

```
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(22869550) called with curMem=948197297, maxMem=1159641169
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO MemoryStore: 33 blocks selected for dropping
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO BlockManager: Dropping block broadcast_1_piece0 from memory
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO BlockManager: Writing block broadcast_1_piece0 to disk
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO BlockManager: Dropping block broadcast_1 from memory
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO BlockManager: Writing block broadcast_1 to disk
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO BlockManager: Dropping block broadcast_0_piece0 from memory
16/05/02 22:46:15 INFO BlockManager: Writing block broadcast_0_piece0 to disk
```

Also in the working node, I see directories from 00-3f without any breaks.

It would seem that there is some background cleanup of blockmgr directories of the failing node, though both nodes are configured similarly.

Any pointers or insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Also, how do you invoke the spark job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, this turned out to be a problem caused by system cleanup routines removing empty directories in the spark tmp directory location.